# Integrar PHP a ElectronJS

Tags: php, javascript, electron

Saludos comunidad. Mi pregunta en cuestión viene porque quiero empezar a desarrollar una aplicación de escritorio con ElectronJS, mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de integrarle PHP como lenguaje de programación o solo debo utilizar NodeJS.
Si alguno de ustedes puede aclararme sobre esta duda que tengo, le agradezco.
He buscado documentacion de Electron pero aun no consigo la forma de poder integrarlo con PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lamentablemente `ElectronJS` solo te permite trabajar con `Javascript` pero a experiencia personal realicé una aplicación con  `Electron` y  `PHP` en Windows lo que hice fue:

- Crear un proyecto exe con [SMART INSTALL MAKER](http://es.sminstall.com/)
- Configurar la instalación de un servidor Apache en un puerto diferente al 80, 8080 ó 8000
- Configurar la instalación de PHP junto a Apache.
- Generar un proyecto Electron para que abra una ventana en la direccion y puerto del servidor Apache ejemplo:

  ```
  app.on('ready', function() {  
     mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
     mainWindow.loadURL('http://127.0.0.1:5000'); //url del servidor

     mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
        mainWindow = null;
     });
  });
  ```
- Agregar todos los archivos necesarios al proyecto, junto a scripts de instalación.
- Generar el exe para la instalación en Windows.

La idea es que puedas usar PHP, si quieres probarlo tienes que tenerlo instalado en cada maquina en donde se usará tu aplicación. 
Otra forma es contratar un Hosting que tenga PHP y hacer que Electron abra la url de tu sitio.
Espero te sirva de algo.

Comment: exactamente eso hare, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede con electron.js es que te permite usar funcionalidades del sistema (crear archivos, enviar notificaciones, correr programas, etc.) atraves de su API, la cual se *accede* por JavaScript. Pero si lo que quieres es usarlo con PHP, simplemente te recuerdo que electron no es mas que un navegador (simplificando). Por lo cual, solo tendrias que hacer un script sencillo para que abra la url donde tengas la aplicación de php corriendo (servidor o en el mismo equipo).

Ej.:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cFggyzThCc

Comment: Gracias Jesús. Ahora entiendo como hacerlo.